# Civicrm Custom Profile Wordpress

Tags: civimember, profile

I have a wordpress site with CiviCRM. I use this to provide a 'members area' for contacts with a civicrm membership.

When contacts first log on
I would like to get each member to fill out a survey, and once they have provided the information - they will no longer need to see it.

I believe the best way to present them with this survey is by using custom fields in a profile and embed it in a wordpress page using shortcodes. But is there a way to hide, or disable the custom profile from the users view once it has been completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as a built-in CiviCRM feature.

Perhaps you don't want to use profiles for this, but could instead use a Wordpress specific form builder? You need some integration with Wordpress because using a state related to whether or not they've filled in a form would be handled within the CMS (which handles user authentications, sessions, etc.).

I believe Wordpress provides a couple of form builder options that integrate with CiviCRM.
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/forms/

Alternatively, you could replace the permissioning with workflow (in a limited way) and use the profile but only link to it at specific times, e.g. via the membership thank you message.

Comment: In the end I chose to use profiles and email the contact a link to the edit profile page. 
I found this article helpful - https://aghstrategies.com/content/how-create-one-click-personalized-links-civicrm-emails

Thanks for your help Alan